# "Google Admin SDK in C#" No department adds

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-admin-sdk

Good morning
I am using the "admin SDK" for creating accounts in C # .Net, but at the time of shipment of the organization or address does not add the user if created but does not add this information, leave the code I'm using.

```
var service1 = new DirectoryService (new BaseClientService.Initializer ()
     {
         HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
         ApplicationName = strApplicationName,
         ApiKey = strApiKey
     });

        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string userId = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Givenname: ");
        string GivenName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Familyname: ");
        string FamilyName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Deparment: ");
        string Deparment = Console.ReadLine();

        User newuserbody = new User();
        UserName newusername = new UserName();
        UserOrganization neworganitation = new UserOrganization();
        //---------------------------------------------
        newusername.GivenName = GivenName;//First Name
        newusername.FamilyName = FamilyName;//Last Name
        newuserbody.Name = newusername;
        //---------------------------------------------
        newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = userId;//Email Address
        newuserbody.Password = Password;
        //--------------------------------------------
        neworganitation.Primary = true;
        neworganitation.CustomType = "";
        neworganitation.Department = Deparment;
        newuserbody.Organizations = neworganitation;
        User results = service1.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question.  What is wrong with your current code are you getting an error?

Comment: I do not receive any error, the problem I have is that making a user get added, does not have the department, and shipping this code:                                      neworganitation.Primary = true;
        neworganitation.CustomType = "";
        neworganitation.Department = Deparment;
        newuserbody.Organizations = neworganitation;